# Arch Linux feeling sluggish

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma

I like Linux because of the speed, but I feel like it's sluggish on the KDE plasma. It takes about 1-2 seconds when "Alt+F2"'ing. So I would just love to verify that KDE plasma is doing all that or if I'm doing something wrong. I did install a full installation of Plasma, xorg and all the graphical groups instead of their minimal installation.

I'm on Ryzen 5 3500, with 16 GB of RAM and GT 1030 with Arch being installed on 120 SSD and /home being on HDD.

Comment: Check if baloo file indexer is up also check the most consuming processes on "top"

Comment: The GT 1030 is a low-end card, and it only has 2GB VRAM.  You might want to turn off some of plasma's graphical bling.  Animations, for example.   Unfortunately, it's a bad time to upgrade a GPU (and has been for almost a year now, and likely to continue being so for at least another 6-12 months. Even the second-hand market is ridiculously over-priced).